# Nginx nodejs problems

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to use nginx to direct a website hosted on port 8080 to domain exemple1.com and another one on port 8081 that i want to redirect to domain exemple2.com.
On the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default i puted this code:

```
location ~/example1/ {
    proxy_pass http://example1.com;
}
location ~/example2/ {
    proxy_pass http://example2.com;
}
```

but i couldn make it work . I am running 2 nodejs servers on the ports i talked about (port 8080 and 8081).
What i am doing wrong and how to "fix "
it?

Answer (score 1):

Because the downstream app server running on different ports(`listen`) than coming in, you need to specify ports in proxy_pass. So I think

```
listen 8080; 

location ~/example1/ {
    proxy_pass http://example1.com:8080;
}
location ~/example2/ {
    proxy_pass http://example2.com:8081;
}
```

Comment: but when i do sudo nginx -t i get this:
nginx: [emerg] "listen" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test faile

Comment: @FlorinBaciu you create a .conf file under /etc/nginx/conf.d and you can have `server { listen ... }` inside.